# Optarg and Command Line Arguments

Tags: c, malloc, command-line-arguments

I am getting command line arguments from the user.

I then do switch cases for the commands, for example:

```
    case 'f':
         *file_name = optarg;
         break;
```

I am unsure if I need to malloc for the pointer since I don't fully understand optarg.

This is how file_name is declared:

```
char **file_name;
```

Should I do

```
int length = strlen(optarg); // This gives a warning about types when compiling.
```

Then malloc for the string length + 1?

How should the malloc be done for this kind of problem? Remember the user is typing in the file_name into **argv.

**EDIT:** This is how I am calling this function and still getting segmentation fault.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char **file_name;
   parser(argc, argvm file_name);
}

void parser(int argc, char **argv, char **file_name)
{
  // Switch cases.
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'optarg' is just a pointer to an element in argv[]. So, it's safe to not allocate memory and copy the value which 'optarg' points to.

Suppose your programm is called with the following arguments:

```
myapp -a "hello" -b "world"
```

and your code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>

void parse_options(int argc, char* argv[], char ** first_arg, char ** second_arg)
{
  const char* opt_string = "a:b:";
  int opt = -1;
  opt = getopt(argc, argv, opt_string);
  while (opt != -1) {
    switch(opt) {
      case 'a':
        *first_arg = optarg; /* points to argv[2]="hello" */
        break;
      case 'b':
        *second_arg = optarg; /* points to argv[4]="world" */
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    opt = getopt(argc, argv, opt_string);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char* first = 0;
  char* second = 0;
  parse_options(argc, argv, &first, &second);
  printf("first=%s, second=%s\n", first, second);
  return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
freebsd% gcc -Wall main.c
freebsd% ./a.out -a hello -b world
first=hello, second=world
```

Comment: I keep getting Segmentation fault on this line file_name = optarg; Does it matter if I am doing this inside a function? (I will post the code above)

Comment: My logic is that I need to pass a pointer to the file_name pointer in order to receive the file name back in main.

Comment: I made some working example (see edited text), hope this helps.

Comment: Yep it did. I was calling the function but not giving it the address of file_name. &file_name. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You say you have:

```
char **file_name;
...
switch (opt)
{
case 'f':
     *file_name = optarg;
     break;
...
}
```

The code crashes because you've not allocated space or initialized the variable `file_name`.

What you need to do depends on what you want to happen.  Most usually, you would change the definition of `file_name` to:

```
char *file_name = 0;
...
switch (opt)
{
case 'f':
     file_name = optarg;
     break;
...
}
```

This allows you to detect, after the loop/switch, whether a file name was provided, and you can provide a default or report an error if not. You can detect in the case whether a file name was provided previously and object if it was.

The alternative scheme is that you want to allow multiple uses of `-f` on the command line.  Then you need to build up an array of pointers, keeping a count of them.  You might write:

```
char **file_name = 0;
size_t num_files = 0;
size_t max_files = 0;
...
switch (opt)
{
case 'f':
     if (num_files == max_files)
     {
         size_t new_files = (max_files + 2) * 2;
         void  *new_space = realloc(file_name, new_files * sizeof(*file_name));
         if (new_space == 0)
             ...report out of memory error...
         file_name = new_space;
         max_files = new_files;
     }
     file_name[num_files++] = optarg;
     break;
...
}
```

This uses the odd property of `realloc()` that if the pointer passed in is NULL, it simulates `malloc()`.  Alternatively, you can do an initial `malloc()` allocation outside the loop and do (the same) `realloc()` inside the loop.  The calculation on the size allocates 4 entries the first time around, then 12, then 28, etc.  If you're worried about the over-allocation, you can use `realloc()` again after the loop is done to resize to the correct size, but it likely won't affect things much.

After the loop, you have a list of files which you might process with:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_files; i++)
    process_file(file_name[i]);
```